# Where to add signup button in a form in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

In my login form page I want to add signup button nearer to login.. When I was trying to add signup button it performs same action as when we click in login button.. So anyone kindly help me to add that.. this is my loginform.js page

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { login } from '../../redux/reducer';
    import './LoginForm.css';
    import './UserPage';
    import avatar from '../../avatar.png';
    import Back from '../../Back.js';
    import './Registration.js';
    import {withRouter,BrowserRouter as  Link  } from 'react-router-dom';

    class LoginForm extends Component {


      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      }

       componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (!nextProps.isLoginPending && this.props.isLoginPending) {
          if (nextProps.isLoginSuccess) {
             this.props.history.push('/UserPage')
          } else {
            console.log(this.props.loginError)
          }
        }
      }

      render() {
        let {username, password} = this.state;
        let {isLoginPending, isLoginSuccess, loginError} = this.props;

        return (
              <div>
                <Back/>
             <header>
       <h1 className="log">Company Login</h1>
       </header>

          <form name="loginForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <div className="imgcontainer">
        <img src={avatar} alt={"Avatar"} className={"avatar"}/>
      </div>

            <div className="form-group-collection">
              <div className="form-group">

                <label>Username/User ID:</label>
                <input name="username" onChange={e => this.setState({username: e.target.value})} value={username}/>
              </div>


              <div className="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => this.setState({password: e.target.value})} value={password}/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" />


      </form>
    <div>
  <form>
           <Link to={`/Registration`}>
           <button role="link">Sign up</button>
         </Link>
         </form>
         </div>


         </div> 
        )
      }


       onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let { username, password } = this.state;
        this.props.login(username, password);
        this.setState({
          username: '',
          password: ''
        });
      }
    }


    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        isLoginPending: state.isLoginPending,
        isLoginSuccess: state.isLoginSuccess,
        loginError: state.loginError
      };
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
      };
    }
    LoginForm = withRouter(LoginForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

I want to redirect to register.js page whenever I clicked in signup button..

Comment: Are u using signup button of type submit?

Comment: ya...I tried that..

Comment: could u please add html for it here

Comment: Pardon,I can't understand  which code you intent..This is the only page related to form.. No html pages here rather than index.html..

Comment: please update the above code with  signup button

Comment: I updated my code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add something like this and you'll need to have register in your routes configuration.

```
  <Link to={`/register`}>
   <button role="link">Sign up</button>
  </Link>
```

Comment: Thanku @supra28 but it doesn't route to registration page.. When I click signup button Just a blinking occurs.. I updated my code with your code that is given above.. Please take a look and what changes I need to make?

Comment: Change this     import {withRouter,BrowserRouter as  Link  } from 'react-router-dom';

to     import {withRouter, Link  } from 'react-router-dom';